# Handle big bytes when receiving from serial port in c#

Tags: c#, .net, byte

I am new in the serial port. Currently, my project is to extract data from the machine. I'm getting data via an event onDataReceive and the machine is sending bytes.

My problem is that the first wave of bytes seemed to be converted correctly to string but in the second batch of bytes, I got garbage data.

Screen Shot of the output(this is the output given by the multi-currency reader machine:
[image]

The garbage data is I think the Serial Nos.

Here is my code in onDataReceive method:

```
private void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            // Initialize a buffer to hold the received data
            byte[] buffer = new byte[serialPort.ReadBufferSize];
            //// There is no accurate method for checking how many bytes are read
            //// unless you check the return from the Read method
            int bytesRead = serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            String asd = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            //// For the example assume the data we are received is ASCII data.
            tString += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            temp += System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            temp2 += System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\OutputTextFiles\WriteLines.txt", tString);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\OutputTextFiles\WriteLines2.txt", temp);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\OutputTextFiles\WriteLines3.txt", temp2);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to put the output with a txt file.

I hope someone could help me in my problem. Any tips and suggestions in data handling especially bytes?

Comment: I take it from the file name that we're looking at the UTF32 decoded data? Decoding that piece by piece is obviously dangerous, what if the number of bytes received is not a multiple of 4? Better just receive everything first and only *then* decode it.

Comment: Try to use `String asd = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);`  instead of ASCII.GetString.

Comment: @harold thanks for the tips. I'll try :)

Comment: @stomtech thank you. I'll try this one :)

Comment: I suspect you get bitten by a re-enrant event. Remove the while loop, only reead once per event.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I tried to remove the loop but no good :(

Comment: is there any encryption in bytes?

Comment: "but no good" doesn't mean  anything. Also,  `buffer.Length` is just the upper bound, use `BytesToRead` instead.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've tried to use BytesToRead but the output was the same. I've been wondering why the garbage data is on serial nos. only? Can you help analyze the output data?

Comment: No, you need the specification here. And when that is not available, do get a Hex viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the size of `serialPort.ReadBufferSize` I can only suspect that your buffer is breaking the encoding bytes of your string. A character can be made of one or more bytes.

The trick is to read all of the bytes before decoding the string.

Try this example program:

```
var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
var message = "I am new in serial port. Currently my project is to extract data from machine.";
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(message)))
{
    var bytes = new List<byte>();
    var buffer = new byte[23];
    var bytesRead = ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
        bytes.AddRange(buffer.Take(bytesRead));
        bytesRead = ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(bytes.ToArray(), 0, bytes.Count));
}
```

It will output the following:

```
I am new in�
猀攀爀椀愀氀 瀀漀爀琀�
. Currently�
洀礀 瀀爀漀樀攀挀琀 �
is to extra�
琀 搀愀琀愀 昀爀漀洀�
 machine.
I am new in serial port. Currently my project is to extract data from machine.
```

The final line is correct because it uses all of the bytes to decode. The previous lines have errors because I've used a buffer size of 23 which breaks the string encoding.

Comment: I'm getting an exception. "The operation has timed out." what should I do?

Comment: the exception was gone but the garbage data for serial no was there. :(

Comment: no error. but still the garbage is there just like the picture on my post. I think there's something in encoding of serial nos. I just don't have any idea huhu

Comment: @jejerome - Please clarify for me if you're saying that my code doesn't work for you or if it's yours you're talking about?

Comment: hello. Your code is working. but the data I get is still garbage. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @jejerome - I suggest that you get your data and load it in to a `MemoryStream` and then put it through my code and see if it works.

Comment: hmmmm? I will store the data in bytes using MemoryStream? then read it also using MemoryStream? Do you have sample code?

Comment: MemoryStream is not the answer for garbage data huhu

Comment: @jejerome - Yes, but my code works from a `MemoryStream` so if your bytes work then you can use that to debug.

Comment: hello. Is there any possbility that the Serial Numbers are Image data?

Comment: @jejerome - It's your data. You'd have to tell me that.

Comment: I'm just extracting the data from machine. Should I ask the manufacturer? I'm not the one who sends the data that's why I have no idea what encoding was used. :(

Comment: @jejerome - I suspect that you should try to get some clarity on what you're expecting to receive so you know how to handle it.

Comment: Yep. I'm trying to contact the supplier of the machine I'm using to provide me some info. Thanks BTW